Drag and drop file from android device to web page not working
I need my users to be able to drag and drop audio and video files into my web page.
A simple example from MDN works well when the files come from the hard disk, an external USB hard drive or a USB memory stick. Trouble is, the files will be on an android device connected with a USB cable. Users can navigate to the android camera folder easily enough but the drag and drop does not work.
Here is a simple web page (derived from the MDN Dag and Drop Files Article) that demonstrates the problem.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script>
        function dropHandler(evt)
        {
            evt.preventDefault();
            if (evt.dataTransfer.items)
            {
                // Use DataTransferItemList interface to access the file(s)
                [...evt.dataTransfer.items].forEach((item, i) =>
                {
                    if (item.kind === "file")
                    {
                        const file = item.getAsFile();
                        console.log(`… file[${i}].name = ${file.name}`);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log("Item is not a file");
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (evt.dataTransfer.files)
            {
                // Use DataTransfer interface to access the file(s)
                [...evt.dataTransfer.files].forEach((file, i) =>
                {
                    console.log(`… file[${i}].name = ${file.name}`);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("no items. No files");
            }

        }
        function dragOverHandler(evt)
        {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="drop_zone" ondrop="dropHandler(event);"   ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Anyone got any ideas why this is not working to drag files from an android device.

What operating system are you using? And with any other file it works fine?
